# Javascript documentation standards

Tags: javascript, documentation

I have a question that I have tried researching, maybe i'm putting it into the wrong words.

Question: Is there a professional expected style of documenting your javascript files, functions, etc similar to

```
/**
* Method that sum's x + 5
* @param x 
*/
public void sum(int x)
{
  //code  (x + 5)
}
```

sorry if this is a bad example! but i hope my question makes sense

Comment: There is no standard. Most people use JSDoc http://usejsdoc.org/

Comment: @bob What does crockford have to do with documenting code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a standard.  However, the C standard of using a /** to start an block to explain a function is still a good one to use.  This allows programs that scan code looking for function/method descriptors to find it easily.  It also makes it easier for the programmer, as switching languages doesn't require switching commenting styles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for shedding some light! i will continue to document this way